# Resolve Warning: DOMNode::cloneNode(): ID mainBodyArea already defined

Tags: php

While running third party php application i get this type of warning:`Warning: DOMNode::cloneNode(): ID mainBodyArea already defined in /libraries/content-extractor/ContentExtractor.php on line 676`

Followed by another warning:
`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at libraries/content-extractor/ContentExtractor.php:676) in libraries/feedwriter/FeedWriter.php on line 103`

lines in ContentExtractor.php near 676..

```
if (isset($this->body)) $this->body = $this->body->cloneNode(true);
$success = $this->readability->init();
```

lines in FeedWriter.php near line 103

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        $this->json = new stdClass();
```

I am stuck here few hours because if this. I am new to php concepts.
Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't getting entirely this error but have just fixed something incredibly similar, mine was.

```
DOMNode::cloneNode() [<a href='domnode.clonenode'>domnode.clonenode</a>]: ID header already defined in dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php on line 128
```

I was making a pdf with the html of:

```
$html = '<html><head>
  <style>
    @page { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0px; }
    #header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 50px; right: 0px; height: 70px; text-align: center; }
    #footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 50px; right: 0px; height: 70px; text-align: center; }
    #content { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 160px; right: 0px; text-align:center; height:934px; width:934px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    header content
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    main content
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    footer content
  </div>
</body>
</html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
```

To fix the problem all I did was change the id's to classes:

```
$html = '<html><head>
  <style>
    @page { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin:0px; }
    .header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 50px; right: 0px; height: 70px; text-align: center; }
    .footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 50px; right: 0px; height: 70px; text-align: center; }
    .content { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 160px; right: 0px; text-align:center; height:934px; width:934px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    header content
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    main content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer content
  </div>
</body>
</html>';
```

I hope that helps or gets you a step closer to fixing the issue!